# Adding AJAX mechanism on the Groovy controller?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a scenario where I use JS(KNOCKOUT) to call Groovy controller and that indeed invokes a service call to the backend. The groovy controller calls about 4 different services when this process is invoked from frontend. Groovy controller currently works in the order how its been coded and waits for each services to complete its task before the other, which is correct. I need to re-factor code so that the service calls should run parallel(not wait for one another, kind of AJAX nature). I understand I can use Threads to achieve it. Is there any other library or Groovy functionality that I can make use of?

I cannot use groovy.Async because we use grails 2.2.2 in our project. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [Executor grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/executor).

Comment: Thank you. I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GPARS](http://gpars.codehaus.org/). It's got a very good reputation as a parallelism API for Groovy.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried Gpars. Its cool plugin for groovy. However, it didnt quite work when I tried Gpars Agent api. I will check more on that. Thanks for the help.